# How can I remove the bottom border with CSS?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, accordion

I'm using bootstrap and I have adapted the accordion to a table, it works perfectly except the icon when "toggled open" display a border-bottom which I would like to remove. It is probably something inherit somewhere but I cannot figure it out.

Problem:
[image: icon with border]

When collapsed it works fine:
[image: icon collapsed]

Here is the table code:

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .accordion-line-button {
      padding: 0;
      width: auto;
      border: none;
    }
```

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <table class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <tr class="accordion-item">
        <td class="accordion-header" id="heading1">
          <button class="accordion-button accordion-line-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1"></button>
        </td>
        <td class="accord">
          Question
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" id="collapse1" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body">Answer
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Here a link to the [bin](https://jsbin.com/joxumaqude/edit?html,css,output). I'm using a template which I've included and it is the problem, there is something that is inheriting that I cannot figure it out.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I've converted your posted HTML and CSS to a Stack Snippet, but obviously it needs more code adding - but only the "*[mcve]*" code necessary - to reproduce the problem you describe. Please [edit] your question, and update the Snippet.

Comment: don't you think it is just border on image? or you need to update size of image using css?

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks for the edit and I've included the link to the bin where the problem is replicated.

Comment: @demo there is no image, it is an icon positioned `:after` the `<button>` but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a border property but rather box-shadow that is set on the button. Kindly use below code.

```
.accordion-line-button {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks!